# Defining a config file or library file in servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

First of all, i m new to Servlets and JSP. I m learning these my own. I have a doubt. **How can i create a config file or library file in Servlets?** It means I need to keep database connections in one Servlet and want use the variables throughout entire project. Also i need to create some common functions in one Servlet and want to call those functions wherever i need.

Can i achieve these things in Servlets? It is possible in other environment like PHP etc.. But i dont know how to do these in Servlets? I spent last few days to figure it out. But i couldnt make it.

Please help me to solve these things..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can achieve that, but not using a servlet. What you need is to define a Common class that will hold all your common methods and variables like the one below

```
public class Common {
  public static final String DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "en"; //better to have private variables with public setters and getters
  ....
  public static String getDateFormatted(.....) {...}
  ....

}
```

It is better to create a separate database class for controlling your database interaction. Lets say:

```
public class DBConnection { 
  private Connection dbCon;
  //its more convenient to implement the connect on the no ArgumentCostructor
  ....
  public boolean connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {...}
  public ResultSet execSQL(...)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException {...}
}
```

If you want to use a global parameter from within a java class you just call

```
String formatedDate = Common.getDateFormatted(date);
```

Or for db connectivity stuff you can call

```
DBConnection con = new new DBConnection ();
rs = con.execSQL(sql);
```

Comment: Thanks MaVRoSCy.. Let me try with your idea. Then get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

check this simple article  [By Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/configurejsp.html)

on how to use Servlets and configure Servlets !

Comment: Thanks for replying Viral. This s not i m looking for. I know how to configure JSP, Servlet and all. But I need to create a common servlet, which will be used in entire project.. I can use the common servlet to define a database connectivity and define some constants.. Hope u understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your database connection parameter in web .xml init parameters like this

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>dburl</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:mysql:///MY_DB</param-value>
</init-param>
```

And get the value in servlet using
String myDbUrl = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("dburl");

You can also use tomcat Server.xml file for database connection.